# Avro Schema Data Validations with Regular Expressions in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, avro, jackson-dataformat-avro

I'm very new to Using AVRO Schema and I have a use case where I need to validate AVRO schema data with regular expressions. I mean the field value can allow Numbers OR only allow Alphabets OR AlphaNumeric values OR fixed min-max length etc. I tried like below but it's not working. if any idea please assist me for the same .

AVRO schema is :

{
"type": "record",

"name": "Employee",

"namespace": "com.test.avro",

"fields": [

```
{
  "name": "empId",
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "[1-9]"
},

{
  "name": "empName",
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]"
},

{
  "name": "createdDate",
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^[1-9]$"
},

{
   "name": "mobile",
   "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^[1-9]*$"
}
```

]
}

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The [Avro specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/specification/) does not define validation. The Avro specification does not define the "pattern" attribute. Avro schema attributes not defined in the specification are permitted as metadata, but implementations are not required to process them.

Comment: Chin Huang, Thanks for the response . As we saw documentation they were not mention these type of validations. But I was looked into some blogs which shown Data validation with RegExp. Please look into the below link

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#schema_complex